# Save text file with information from JFrame textboxes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I am new to java and am writing am invoicing program where i want to save the user input in txtContact, txtCompany, txtEmail, txtAddress, and txtPhone and text for example the save file will have Contact: txtContact and put into a text file using buffered writer.

This is my code so far:

```
package InvoiceApp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

/**
 *
 * @author dancastillo
 */
public class Customer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form cus
     */
    private String data;
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    public Customer() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtCompany = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtContact = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtAddress = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtPhone = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtEmail = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnSave = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnReset = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnExit = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Company:");

        jLabel2.setText("Contact:");

        jLabel3.setText("Address:");

        jLabel4.setText("Phone:");

        jLabel5.setText("E-Mail:");

        btnSave.setText("Save");
        btnSave.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnSaveActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnReset.setText("Reset");
        btnReset.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnResetActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });


    private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int retValue = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        if(retValue == chooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(data));//data is string to save
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
            String str;
            while((str = reader.readLine())!= null){
                writer.write(str + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error!");
                    }
        }
    }                                       

    private void btnResetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        txtCompany.setText("");
        txtContact.setText("");
        txtAddress.setText("");
        txtPhone.setText("");
        txtEmail.setText("");

    }                                        




    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Customer().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnExit;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnReset;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnSave;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtAddress;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtCompany;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtContact;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtEmail;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtPhone;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Great, so what's your question?  You'll have to be more specific...

Answer (score 0):

Inside `btnSaveActionPerformed` method you could write the content of the `JTextField` components into the file with,

```
private void btnResetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
...
writer.write(txtCompany.getText() + "," + txtContact.setText() + "," + txtAddress.setText() + "," + txtPhone.getText() + "," + txtEmail.setText() +  System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            resetForm();
        }
    });
...
}

private void resetForm() {
            txtCompany.setText("");
            txtContact.setText("");
            txtAddress.setText("");
            txtPhone.setText("");
            txtEmail.setText("");
}
```